# Can't connect via RDP to Windows server

Tags: windows, telnet, rdp

I cant access a server Windows 2008 via RDP. I had to login to the VCenter where the server is located in order to have access. I verified that the Remote Host service is enabled and that the default port for RDP is 3389, the firewall is disabled(it cannot be blocking the connection), the FIPS cryptography is also disabled. So far the only thing that I have found is that when I telnet this way:

telnet [host_name] 3389 the connection is established.

When I telnet [ip_adress] 3389 the connection is also established, but when I telnet with just the host it doesn't allow me to connect:

telnet [host/ip_adress]

What could be the issue here??

Answer (score 1):

Your last telnet is trying to connect to port 25 which is obviously not your target.

I think you should change the remote setting of your windows server 2008 from properties of PC and remote connection tab. There is 2 different security options for remote desktop which determines possibility of user's connections.